# ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, multi-index, valueerror

I am getting this error while working with a dataset

```
ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value
```

I used this code previously but always run well for the same type of data but now it is not working.

```
for dataset in data_df:
dataset.at[dataset['Ozone'] <= 54, 'Ozone'] = 0,
dataset.at[(dataset['Ozone'] > 54) & (dataset['Ozone'] <= 70), 'Ozone'] = 1,
dataset.at[(dataset['Ozone'] > 70) & (dataset['Ozone'] <= 85), 'Ozone'] = 2,
dataset.at[(dataset['Ozone'] > 85) & (dataset['Ozone'] <= 105), 'Ozone'] = 3,
dataset.at[(dataset['Ozone'] > 105) & (dataset['Ozone'] <= 200), 'Ozone'] = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove commas after each line like this and run again

```
for dataset in data_df:
dataset.at[dataset['Ozone'] <= 54, 'Ozone'] = 0
dataset.at[(dataset['Ozone'] > 54) & (dataset['Ozone'] <= 70), 'Ozone'] = 1
dataset.at[(dataset['Ozone'] > 70) & (dataset['Ozone'] <= 85), 'Ozone'] = 2
dataset.at[(dataset['Ozone'] > 85) & (dataset['Ozone'] <= 105), 'Ozone'] = 3
dataset.at[(dataset['Ozone'] > 105) & (dataset['Ozone'] <= 200), 'Ozone'] = 4
```